# in what language is Asana written?

Tags: frameworks, asana

I see that the Asana API has is made in ruby

How is the backend created? 
Does it use some know web framework such as Rails?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the Asana site:

> ## Luna, our in-house framework for writing great web apps
>
> When writing a complex, highly-responsive web application, there are all kinds of really difficult programming tasks that you end up doing over and over again for every feature you want to write. These are pains all too familiar to authors of Web2.0-style software (and interactive software in general). When we started Asana, we knew we wanted to build an application that is simultaneously very sophisticated in functionality and very fast in experience, and felt that the existing toolset just wasn't up to snuff. So we built Luna, an in-house end-to-end framework that automates the busy work of writing rich web applications to an unprecedented degree.

[more from their site here](https://asana.com/developers/)